# Extract value from array then run if on value

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have an array of items (cheese) in a checkbox format like so

```
array(
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    "holder" => "div",
    "class" => "",
    "heading" => __("Choose your cheese topping", 'rbm_menu_item'),
    'param_name' => 'cheesbox',
    'value' => array( 'Cheddar'=>'Chedder', 'Gouda'=>' Gouda', 'Bleu'=>' Bleu'),
    "description" => __("<br /><hr class='gduo'>", 'rbm_menu_item')
    ),
```

The values of the array are displayed on a page (in a hidden div) using the heredoc declaration with an if to check if the checkbox has been used - if the return is empty the div does not show - if one of the checkboxes is "checked" then it does.

```
///Cheese selections
if (!empty($cheesbox)) {
      $output .= <<< OUTPUT
        <br />
        <div class="sides">Comes with: <p>{$cheesebox}</p></div>
        <br />
OUTPUT4;
}
```

What I need to do is pull any one of the values in the array and if its in the $cheesebox the do something.

Ive tried using an ifelse like this

```
if ( ('$cheesebox') == "Cheddar" ){
           echo "Your topping is Cheddar";
        }
            elseif ( ('$cheesebox') == "Gouda" ){
        {
           echo "Your topping is Gouda";
        }
            elseif ( ('$cheesebox') == "Bleu" ){
        {
           echo "Your topping is Bleu";
        }
```

however this does not work - I'm sure I have it wrong somehere along the line or does the heredoc function only allow for one?

if so is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is `$cheesebox`? or `$cheesbox`?

Comment: Also, `('$cheesebox')` is a __literal__ string. Obviously the literal string `'$cheesebox'` will never match the literal string `'Cheddar'`. This is like saying `if (1 == 2)`, the condition will just never be true. It's obvious just from statically analyzing the code. The value never changes. If you meant to do `if ($cheesebox == "Cheddar")` instead then you should use that.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes in PHP mean a literal string with no parsing of variables. Try this:

```
  if ($cheesebox == "Cheddar") {
       echo "Your topping is Cheddar";
  } else if ($cheesebox == "Gouda") {
       echo "Your topping is Gouda";
  }  else if ($cheesebox == "Bleu") {
       echo "Your topping is Bleu";
  }
```

Better yet:

```
 if (in_array($cheesebox, ['Cheddar', 'Gouda', 'Bleu'])) {
     echo "Your topping is {$cheesebox}";
 }
```

EDIT: In response to your further requirements in the comments:

In your PHP:

```
$cheeses = ['Cheddar', 'Gouda', 'Bleu'];
$cheeseBoxes = '';
foreach ($cheeses as $cheese) {
    $cheeseClass = $cheesebox == $cheese ? '' : 'cheese-hidden';
    $cheeseBoxes .= <<<CHEESE
    <div class="cheese {$cheeseClass}">
       <p>Cheese: {$cheese}</p>
       <img src="/images/cheeses/{$cheese}.png" alt="A picture of some {$cheese}" />
    </div>
CHEESE;
}

// Then, wherever you need it, or just use $cheeseBoxes in your chosen heredoc:
echo $cheeseBoxes;
```

In your CSS, to hide the inactive ones:

```
.cheese.cheese-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Both of those work - however it throws the echo to the top of the page out side of the container div. Is the a way to run it inside the heredoc OUTPUT4?

Comment: Yes, if you set a new variable called $cheeseboxOutput, then use that in the heredoc. Ideally you would have completely separate view and display logic, using something like a templating engine, but I realise you might not be there yet.

Comment: In order to have a variable called $cheeseboxOutput - I could then run it in the heredoc with styling - that I understand, but... now I would need another function to take the result of the echo and pass that to $cheeseboxOutput  - dont know how to do that

Comment: The idea is to have each item whether Cheddar, Gouda, Bleu display in its own div with text - that div will also contain a different image - on load all divs are hidden and only show if the corresponding $cheesebox value is returned.

Comment: This works - itplaces the result in the assigned div in the OUTPUT4 heredoc section and uses CHEESE (im gonna have to rename all that - it getting to cheesy, to follow :)

Comment: but the image - i used the appropriate path for the image make an image with cheddar as the name in a dir called assets (change from images/cheeses/ - no see though - wonder why?

Comment: oh and this - the reason I used a checkbox is because if you look all the way at the top ( 'type' => 'checkbox', ) in that - I tried to get a radio instead but it didnt respond to either: 'type' => 'radio', OR 'type' => 'radiogroup', so, I had to settle for the checkbox and hope the user doesnt get trigger-happy.